# Can tesseract-ocr be trained to extract document content such as Title, Authors, Abstract, and references?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I am investigating different approaches to extracting information from structured text.

Currently I am using `org.apache.pdfbox` to convert `PDF` documents to `png` images then processing these images with `Tesseract`.

Tesseract version:-

```
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'tesseract', version: '3.04.01-1.3'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'tesseract', version: '3.04.01-1.3', classifier: 'macosx-x86_64'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'opencv', version: '3.2.0-1.3'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.73-1.3'
compile group: 'org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets', name: 'leptonica', version: '1.73-1.3', classifier: 'macosx-x86_64'
```

The information I require form any structured document includes.

1). Document Title
2). Document Author(s)
3). References (e.g. citations)

Is this possible with Tesseract? Do I have to (re)train tesseract?